# Determining the path in fs.readFile()

Tags: node.js, json, macos, path, exe

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json', 'utf8'));
```

This is the code for my app (index.js) . It uses a file named config.json using a relative path `./config.json`. When I compile this into my mac using `$pkg index.js`, I obtain a `test-macos` file that is my app. Both the app and the config.json file are located in the same folder named project (this is why I can use the relative path `./config.json`). However, once runnning the app I run into an error:

```
/Users/amelie/Documents/project/test-macos ; 

exit; internal/fs/utils.js:312 
throw err;

 ^ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './config.json'.
```

Therefore it seems that my app cannot find the config.json file. I could determine an absolute path but I need these two files to always be together because I need the path in the variable

```js
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json', 'utf8'));
```

to be always the same since I share those files to other people and the absolute path would therefore change. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: What's the process' working directory? And you're sure `config.json` is inside that directory?

Comment: I'm not sure at all ! I don't really understand this part. Are you telling me that the app is running in another directory and not inside the project folder ? Would that mean I need to include the file in working directory using $pkg index.js --assets "config.json", which stores a file named config.json located in the root directory of my project and then added to my app ?

Comment: I don't know, you should know that better than me. But the `fs.readFileSync('./etc')` reads relatively to the process' working directory.

Comment: Could you add an image with your project structure? This would be helpful to check if the relative path is correct after compilation